# Link to not rendering the component again

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using React **Link to=""** property. I have a url like below.

> http://localhost:3000/work/109

After clicking on link, It is successfully going to url like below, But not re-rendering the component again.

> http://localhost:3000/work/107

Below is my file, where i am using react-router

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const RouteWithSubRoutes = route => (
 <React.Fragment>
   <Route exact path="/" render={()=>(<Redirect to="/home" />)}/>
   <Route exact path={route.path} render={props => (
   <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes} onOpenNav={route.onOpenNav}/>
 )} />
 </React.Fragment>
);
```

Is there any other property of React, which i am not using.

**Note: I am going to same url, But with diffrence id.**

Comment: Please see creating a [mcve]. We need to see code, in order to assist you.

Comment: I think you are not using router, it will render the same thing even if a path param is changed

Comment: I am using react-router

Comment: please give a working example. The question is too vague

Comment: I edited the code with my file where i am using react-router.

Comment: Rajat, consider creating an example on codepen/ codesandbox. 
However, as per my obsevation, you are not embedding Routes in Switch.
<Switch/> tag I meant.

Answer (score 0):

you should use 'react-router' [params](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params) in your `Route` component path.
also this way new params would send to your component after clicking on `Link` component.

you could check `this.props.match.params` to sure it gets update.

then since you want component to re-render you should use [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) to get new value and set it to your state.

Comment: They are examples on provided links.